# Group columns based on the headers if they are found in the same list. Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, group-by, pandas-groupby

So I have a data frame that is something like this

```
Resource    2020-06-01     2020-06-02     2020-06-03
Name1            8               7              8    
Name2            7               9              9 
Name3            10              10             10
```

Imagine that the header is literal all the days of the month. And that there are way more names than just three.

I need to reduce the columns to five. Considering the first column to be the days between `2020-06-01` till `2020-06-05`. Then from Saturday till Friday of the same week. Or the last day of the month if it is before Friday. So for June would be these weeks:

```
week 1: 2020-06-01 to 2020-06-05
week 2: 2020-06-06 to 2020-06-12
week 3: 2020-06-13 to 2020-06-19
week 4: 2020-06-20 to 2020-06-26
week 5: 2020-06-27 to 2020-06-30
```

I have no problem defining these weeks. The problem is grouping the columns based on them.
I couldn't come up with anything.

Does someone have any ideas about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to use these code to generate your dataframe.

```
dates = pd.date_range(start='2020-06-01', end='2020-06-30')
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name1': np.random.randint(1, 10, size=len(dates)),
    'Name2': np.random.randint(1, 10, size=len(dates)),
    'Name3': np.random.randint(1, 10, size=len(dates)),
})
df = df.set_index(dates).transpose().reset_index().rename(columns={'index': 'Resource'})
```

Then, the solution starts from here.

```
# Set the first column as index
df = df.set_index(df['Resource'])

# Remove the unused column
df = df.drop(columns=['Resource'])

# Transpose the dataframe
df = df.transpose()

# Output:
Resource    Name1   Name2   Name3
2020-06-01 00:00:00 3   2   7
2020-06-02 00:00:00 5   6   8
2020-06-03 00:00:00 2   3   6
...
```

```
# Bring "Resource" from index to column
df = df.reset_index()
df = df.rename(columns={'index': 'Resource'})

# Add a column "week of year"
df['week_no'] = df['Resource'].dt.weekofyear

# You can simply group by the week no column
df.groupby('week_no').sum().reset_index()

# Output:
Resource    week_no Name1   Name2   Name3
0   23  38  42  41
1   24  37  30  43
2   25  38  29  23
3   26  29  40  42
4   27  2   8   3
```

I don't know what you want to do for the next. If you want your original form, just `transpose()` it back.

***EDIT: OP claimed the week should start from Saturday end up with Friday***

```
# 0: Monday
# 1: Tuesday
# 2: Wednesday
# 3: Thursday
# 4: Friday
# 5: Saturday
# 6: Sunday
df['weekday'] = df['Resource'].dt.weekday.apply(lambda day: 0 if day <= 4 else 1)
df['customised_weekno'] = df['week_no'] + df['weekday']
```

Output:

```
Resource    Resource    Name1   Name2   Name3   week_no weekday customised_weekno
0   2020-06-01  4   7   7   23  0   23
1   2020-06-02  8   6   7   23  0   23
2   2020-06-03  5   9   5   23  0   23
3   2020-06-04  7   6   5   23  0   23
4   2020-06-05  6   3   7   23  0   23
5   2020-06-06  3   7   6   23  1   24
6   2020-06-07  5   4   4   23  1   24
7   2020-06-08  8   1   5   24  0   24
8   2020-06-09  2   7   9   24  0   24
9   2020-06-10  4   2   7   24  0   24
10  2020-06-11  6   4   4   24  0   24
11  2020-06-12  9   5   7   24  0   24
12  2020-06-13  2   4   6   24  1   25
13  2020-06-14  6   7   5   24  1   25
14  2020-06-15  8   7   7   25  0   25
15  2020-06-16  4   3   3   25  0   25
16  2020-06-17  6   4   5   25  0   25
17  2020-06-18  6   8   2   25  0   25
18  2020-06-19  3   1   2   25  0   25
```

So, you can use `customised_weekno` for grouping.

Comment: Thanks, There I tried it and works. There is only one thing, this counts the weeks.
So week number 23 goes from 2020-06-01 till 2020-06-07 when it should go from 2020-06-01 till 2020-06-05. Because in my scenario, all weeks ends in Friday, or the last day of the month if it is not Friday. And always starts on a Saturday, at the exception of day 1 of the month, that starts whenever it starts.

But thanks, this is a major milestone in order to figure out what to do exactly

Comment: @BrunoSapia, I have edited my answer based on your requirements. Please let me know if there are any misunderstanding. Otherwise, please accept my answer so we can close this question.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I used your original way and change it up a little bit in order to work too

dfinal = dfinal.set_index(dfinal['Alias'])
dfinal = dfinal.drop(columns=['Alias'])

dfinal=dfinal.transpose()
dfinal = dfinal.reset_index()
dfinal = dfinal.rename(columns={'index': 'Alias'})



    

dfinal['week_no'] = dfinal['Work Date'].dt.weekofyear.shift(-2).ffill()

dfinal=dfinal.groupby(["week_no"]).sum()

Comment: @BrunoSapia, could you please accept my answer if it led you to what you expected?